# How to calculate $\int_{e^{-2n\pi }}^{1}\left | \frac{d }{dx}\cos\left ( \ln\frac{1}{x} \right ) \right |dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I have no idea on how to calculate
$$\int_{e^{-2n\pi }}^{1}\left | \frac{d }{dx}\cos\left ( \ln\frac{1}{x} \right ) \right |dx$$
any hint would be appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$\mathcal{I}=\int_{e^{-2n\pi }}^{1}\left | \frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d}x}\cos\left ( \ln\frac{1}{x} \right ) \right |\mathrm{d}x=\int_{e^{-2n\pi }}^{1}\left | \frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} x}\cos\left ( \ln x \right ) \right |\, \mathrm{d}x=\int_{e^{-2n\pi }}^{1}\Big | \sin\left ( \ln x \right ) \Big |\frac{1}{x}\, \mathrm{d}x$$
then let $\ln x=t$ we get
$$\mathcal{I}=\int_{-2n\pi }^{0}\Big | \sin t \Big |\, \mathrm{d}t=\int_{0}^{2n\pi }\Big | \sin t \Big |\, \mathrm{d}t$$
hope you can take it from here.

Comment: silly me! I got it! thx